# Set different Width of two columns in Visualforce?

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

I want to set the width of two columns (like left column 70% and right column 30%). 
How can I do that.

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:panelGrid columns="2">
        <apex:detail/>
        <apex:outputText>Here come's the Image</apex:outputText>
    </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<apex:page>
    <script type="text/javascript"        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <apex:panelGrid width="100%" columnClasses="testcc" columns="2">
        <apex:detail/>
        <apex:outputText>Here come's the Image</apex:outputText>
    </apex:panelGrid>
<script>
$(".testcc").each(function( index ) {
   if((index % 2)==0)$(this).css('width','30%');
   else $(this).css('width','70%');
});
<script>
</apex:page>
```